# Jensen's inequality result understanding

Tags: probability

If $f(S)$ is a convex function of a random variable $S$. Also, $E[\epsilon] = 0$. And we use Taylor series expansion around the mean of $S$, i.e. $S=\bar{S}+\epsilon$, then $E[f(S)] = E[f(\bar{S}+\epsilon)]=E[f(\bar{S})+f^{'}(\bar{S})\epsilon+\frac{1}{2} f^{''}(\bar{S})\epsilon ^2 + ...]=E[f(E[S])]+E[f^{'}(\bar{S})\epsilon]+1/2E[f^{''}(E[S])\epsilon ^2]$

why is the above then approximately equal to: $f(\bar{S}) + 1/2f^{''}(\bar{S})E[\epsilon ^2]$ ?

Comment: $f'(\bar{S})$ is a constant, and $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon] = 0$, so the first degree term drops out. The rest is fairly usual truncation.

Comment: oh.. they all are constants, i.e. the functoins with $\bar{S}$